# Find command showing files that do not exist

Tags: rhel7

I recently updated my drupal files from another server.

There are about 50k files.

I need to change the permissions on the files to 644

When I run:

```
find . type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

From with in the files dir.

I get the following output:

```
chmod: cannot access ./file1.jpg No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access ./file2.jpg No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access ./file3.jpg No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access ./file4.jpg No such file or directory
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Those files should not exist, they may have been there before the move but i am not sure.

Comment: Is this actual output, or a made-up example?  Could there be filenames in the list that have spaces in the name?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest:

```
find . type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 644
```

This command will execute chmod with lots of files for each iteration, and won't be impacted if the filenames have special caracters.

Comment: using `find . type f -exec chmod 644 {} +`  should work well too.